# How to initialise map based on user's locale or other geo data available

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

This will be a quite detailed quest on how to initialise the map "properly".

- My preliminary thinking is that when the user open the map control,
  the camera should focus on its currently location if available.
- Otherwise based on the user's locale setting or any other location
  information that's possibly available (e.g. IP based reverse
  geocoding?). Focus on and zoom to the city level of the map.

I understand how to do the first bit by  moving the camera to the location in the

```
onLocationChange(Location location)
```

method.

But I lack the knowledge to do the second bit, can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand off of your question, using `LocationManager` you can get location information from your device using either GPS, Network or even information from other apps that have recently used any of the above to find the location using the "Passive Location" feature.

You can find more details about any of these from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html).

Then you could use `com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate` class to perform focus and zoom on the map using `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(...)` method.

And for geocoding use the [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class.

Comment: I tried the location manager, but in the End I also access the locale setting to help decide the country information if nothing else is available.